# C++ STL-conforming Allocators

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

What allocators are available out there for use with STL when dealing with small objects. I have already tried playing with pool allocators from Boost, but got no performance improvement (actually, in some cases there was considerable degradation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what compiler you use, but it probably comes with a bunch of pre-built allocators. This is on a Mac with [gcc 4.2.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01177.html):

```
~$ find /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ -name "*allocator*"
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/array_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/bitmap_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/debug_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/malloc_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/mt_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/pool_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/throw_allocator.h
```

Here's also a link to [BitMagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/memalloc.html) project page that talks about how to build your own. Also check out small object allocator in the [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) (and the [book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201704315) too).

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Visual C++ standard library implementation provides [several proprietary allocators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292134%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for node-based containers (at least as of the soon-to-be-release Visual Studio 2010).

Answer (score 1):

You need an allocator that's right for your specific needs. The STL generic allocator is the best for the huge variety of circumstances, and if you want a new allocator, you will need to profile and understand your specific requirements. You'll have to be more specific about what container you're going to put these objects in.